# How to reduce the building time for a Qt program

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a Qt project which will take around 15 mins to build the program. Each time when I make a small modification I have to wait for long time.

Is there a method to reduce this build time? Or is there a way to "make only the file which I had modified" and then execute the program?

Comment: How do you build your project?

Comment: In Qt I just uses ctr+R. This builds the project and run

Comment: If you are using Linux use `ccache`.  Is your build using all your cores?  Is your project big?  Does it take less time building after modifying a source, or header file?

Comment: @Jis Is it taking 15 mins every time you build?

Comment: Yes. Irrespective of what changes it make, it will build complete project

Comment: If it happens when changing headers: Reduce the dependencies inside your project, e.g. replace header includes by forward declarations and avoid huge central headers every other file must include.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was rebuilding it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well check whether your are rebuilding in all your program runs. And also whether you are cleaning your project before running it. Because if you do so, it have to regenerate all those `moc` files and output[.o] files needed for execution.

But normally upon a small change, the build doesn't take too much time. I have been developing a project by qt creator,  it doesn't take too much time while building upon a small modification. But if there is clean/rebuild step while every execution, it will definitely take whole build time. And again even if you manually build your project via terminal without the help of IDE, it won't take that much time provided you don't remove the moc files and .o files manually before building after small modifcation.

Comment: How to check if I am rebuilding the whole project?

Comment: i think u were re-building ur whole project every time u even made a small change. check the build log. supposed u changed a file 'A' and only 'A' and output file should be re-built. if other files were also re-built, u were doing re-building whole project.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo How to avoid rebuilding the whole project ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using qrc in your app and there are many files in it, it takes too much time to generate qrc.cpp and qrc.obj files. So try to minimize the number of files in qrc system and also try to minimize the sizes of each file.

Comment: I am using 10 pngs in my qrc. Can I juse those images from the static path directory of the build or release folder ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, usage of **precompiled headers** may help, but effect of that may varay according to you program structure.

Answer (score 0):

The general C++ ways to reduce compile time apply. Don't #include what you don't need. Use class declarations instead of #include'ing the definitions if possible. etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you do that small modification: if you modify something in a header that is included pretty much in every file in your project...

Additionally to above responses, if you work with linux, check out ccache (https://ccache.samba.org/)